Mix clips and audio using Google Transcoder
Im newbie using Google Transcoder API. I need it to join some clips (with their own audio) and one audio more like background music. Im using php.
I have tried several things and read a lot of posts, but none was useful about I need. I tried to add the audio-only as new Input. Also I tried to join the clips and audio in the Atom, but this resets the audio in every clip. I would like a continuous music.
